# How to change a character in a string using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

im having troubles with this code

```
int main() {
     char *My_St = "abcdef";
     *(My_St+1)='+';
     printf("%s\n",My_St);
     return 0;
}
```

i built this code and has no errors, but when i try to run it, it throws a segmentation fault, could someone tell what's wrong

Answer (score 6):

You can't because you are trying to modify const data.

change it to:

```
char My_St[] = "abcdef";
```

Then you will be able to change it.

Think about what you were doing, you were declaring **a pointer** that pointed to `"abcdef"`. It IS a pointer, **not an array** of chars. `"abcdef"` lives in the farm, I mean, in the `.text` area of your program and that is immutable.

When you do it the way I've shown, you are telling the compiler: i'm declaring this array, that will have as many chars as are needed to accommodate `"abcdef"` and also, as you are there, copy `"abcdef"` to it.

Comment: if he changes the line as I said, the next line `*(My_St+1)='+';` will be a valid pointer operation.

Comment: but still using an array... As in sizeof(My_St) = 7, not 1.

Comment: If you really want to be that picky, he said he wants to **change** the array using pointers, nothing more. `*(My_St+1)='+'` is using pointers. I told him to change ONE line of his code. In your answer you are not CHANING anything. Jesus.

Comment: @monadic: If you really want a pointer variable, then you can do `char a[] = "abcdef"; char *My_St = a;`

Answer (score 3):

You provided a hint to the compiler by declaring `My_St` with type `char *`.  Assigning a string literal to this pointer essentially makes it a `const char *` because a string literal cannot be modified, meaning the memory location is read-only.  Writing to that read-only memory location is what is producing your segfault.  Change it from `char *My_St` to `char My_St[]` to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

char *My_St refers to constant memory, most likely. You will need to dynamically allocate your string and then fill it (using strcpy).

```
char *str = malloc(7);
strcpy(str, "abcdef");
```

Or

```
char *str = strdup("abcdef");
```

And then it is safe to modify `str`.

Comment: I actually get no segfault when running it but it prints abcdef, and yes you're right my_st is in the .data section of the program because its a compile time constant

Comment: @Jesus I don't think the specification says that it has to be in constant memory, just that it should be a `const char *`. So its really indeterminate behavior to modify a string literal.

Comment: gcc places it in the .data section because placing such things on the stack is impractical, also the segfault is probably caused from a protected memory access (.data section is protected)

Answer (score 0):

The basics are correct, however your character string is (behind the scenes) constant and can't be modified. You'd have to define a array of chars (e.g. `char[20]`), copy the string into it and then modify the character.

To be 100% correct you'd have to write `const char *My_St = "abcdef";` which makes it clearer that you can't do what you're trying to do.